# Laravel default port api issue

Tags: laravel, api, virtualhost

I have created Laravel api using Dingo package in ht-docs directory. while running **php artisan serve --port=80**, my api application works.

But the remaining projects in the ht-docs directory not working.

**Example API URL :** http://localhost:8080/api/showProgressForm [works good]

**Other Project URL in the same directory:**
http://localhost:8080/mongoproject/index.php [Not Working]

```
Error Message: {"message":"404 Not Found","status_code":404,"debug":{"line":161,
    "file":"D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\projects\\lrs\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php",
    "class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "trace":["#0 D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\projects\\lrs\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(750):
```

how to fix it. Help needed.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show your routes.php and try removing .php  from index.php

Comment: Whhat are you trying to achieve? So there are two servers running, one with laravel the other with something else?

Comment: @kapil

**My route file**

$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');
use Dingo\Api\Auth\Auth;
use Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\OAuth2;
$api->version('v1', function ($api) {
 $api->get('dingohello','App\Http\Controllers\UserController@dingoIndex'); //SAMPLE Code NEEDS TO REMOVE
 $api->post('getAccessToken', function(){
  //return Response::json(Authorizer::issueAccessToken());
 });
});
$api->version('v1', function ($api) {
 $api->get('showProgressForm', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiController@showProgressForm'); 
});

Comment: You should run `artisan serve` on another port. This one is the default for Apache so all every URL you open will go through the Laravel app.

Comment: @Murf - my goal is  to create rest api server using larvel. so I have used oauth_Dingo package. while accessing my api,  I am using 80 port. But in the htdocs the other projects which were running in the same port is not working. sample api code

Comment: @TheFallen. ok. But artisan serve 80 is not feasible in production right?

Comment: For production you should use a virtual host, also for development it's more convenient than running a command each time.